# Glassfish4 tries to inject EJB in Spring context

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-4

I am trying to upgrade to Glassfish 4 for an application that uses a combination of EJBs and Spring beans. This worked fine on Glassfish3.

When i try to deploy I get errors of this type:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomethingLogic with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.my.application.server.service.SomethingServiceSession.somethingLogic
```

At first, I got these in non-spring beans when trying to @Inject a Spring bean (EJBs/webservices/servlets). After changing all @Inject's to @Autowired, the non-spring classes no longer give the error, but I start getting the same errors on the purely Spring beans (so @Inject of a Spring bean to another Spring bean gives the error.)

This leads me to believe that Glassfish will try to look for a EJB when encountering @Inject, no matter if it's in the context of EJB or not, and no matter if the bean to be injected is a EJB or a Spring bean.

Is this the case, and how do I avoid this?

Comment: can you reproduce this problem in a small test project (a small maven project or something else) with your constellation? if it is so... can you post the code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990390/glassfish4-ejb-spring-deploy-fails for some code examples, I added this is a more general question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem, by adding `bean-discovery-mode="none"` to my various `beans.xml` files.